# Eagle won't route airwire to a polygon orphan

Tags: eaglecad, autorouter, polygon, gnd-pour, orphans

On the top GND polygon, I have orphans turned off, yet somehow I'm still getting a polygon on Q1's GND. Eagle won't route a wire to this orphan. I've turned orphans on/off and ratsnest, but nothing has changed. Also Eagle is claiming a 100% route on the autorouter screen.

[UPDATE] After reading the documentation, it seems like orphans are only dropped if they are electrically unconnected. This makes sense why there's a poly on GND, but the question remains, why won't Eagle route to it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> *This makes sense why there's a poly on GND, but the question remains,
> why won't Eagle route to it?*

It's still visible because it picks up GND from Q1's pad but, it can't connect to the rest of the GND circuit because there doesn't appear to be any room for making a connection on the red layer without an infringement of design rules. Hence you get the air wires: -

[image]

Comment: It's a really simple circuit board that it routed in 4 seconds. There's plenty of room for a reroute and that wire to go. The main problem is why it won't connect...when it says that the board is 100% routed

Comment: I've added your actual question to my answer. Plus I've added an image. I cannot say why Eagle reports 100% but, that wasn't your question @AJ_Smoothie On a deeper and more significant level, forget about using an auto-router on this sort of design. All the pros will tell you the same. Also, route as many connections as you can on the top layer and reserve as much of the other layer for a ground-plane.